# In a Xamarin forms application on Mac OS Visual Studio, how can I set the iOS build level?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am getting this error message with AppCenter in my Xamarin Forms application:

```
/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.6-12.1.4/mtouch-cache/AppCenterCrashes.a(MSErrorReport.o)) was built for newer iOS version (9.0) than being linked (8.0)
```

I understand that the fix would be to change the iOS release minimum for the build.

Can anyone tell me in a forms application, how can I set the iOS build level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right Click the info.plist and open it with XML Editor .You can set the **MinimumOSVersion** .Just like the following image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will resolve your problem, but still that is the answer to the question as is, minimal version is set in the info.plist file.